# Python += with a list and a tuple

Tags: python

I saw someone wrote an interesting python line online, but couldn't understand why it works. So we can try the following lines in python interpreter:

```
s=[1]
s=s+(1,-1)
```

This will result in an error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list". But if done in another way:

```
s=[1]
s+=(1,-1)
```

will result in s = [1,1,-1]

So I used to thought x=x+y is equivalent to x+=y, can someone tell me how they are different and why the second way works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first duplicate doesn't answer this - it asks why `+=` changes the list.  The 2nd is more applicable, though the only real attempt to explain `why` is something to do with symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `+=` use `list.extend`:

```
s = [1]
s.extend((1,-1))
```

Comment: Your answer's not that far off.  It looks like `s += ...` is implemented as `s.extend(tuple(...))` (or v.v).  `s += 1,-1` works.

Comment: The prime questions are "*can someone tell me how they are different and why the second way works?*". The OP would like to understand (*I saw someone wrote an interesting python line online, but couldn't understand why it works*), not being provided another solution.